# Use function parameters to declare req.body.parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I want to make a function if I call with different parameters it should use the parameters to define a req.body for using in view. Bad description, I'll show what I mean:
This func

```
function savePaintingsAll(post, profilpictureEncoded,paintingsname,paintingstype) {
    if (profilpictureEncoded == null) return;
    const profpic = JSON.parse(profilpictureEncoded);
    if (profpic != null && imageMimeTypes.includes(profpic.type)) { // If the file is a json obj & from the type image (jpg, png)
        const name = paintingsname;
        const type = paintingstype;
        post.name = new Buffer.from(profpic.data, 'base64')    // Buffer.from(where, how)
        post.type = profpic.type
    }
}
```

I want the parameters paintingsname and paintingstype to define if i call `savePaintingsAll(post, req.body.paintings3, paintings3, paintingsType3)` but if I do so the parameters arent used inside the function ether if I put them in or outside the if statement. Where is the issue?I use ejs, express.
I need to use the data to save diffrent paintings in DB and display them:

```
<img id="painting" class="" style="max-width: 20%; min-width: 300px; height: auto;"src="<%= post.paintingsP %>" />
    <img id="painting2" class="" style="max-width: 20%; min-width: 300px; height: auto;"src="<%= post.paintingsP2 %>" />
```

Comment: Where do you need to **use** those two data items? Your example doesn't use them at all. Please [edit] your question to explain.

Comment: Okay, i need them to dispaly images and save each image seperate inside a DB